# Pipe stdin into "expect" script

Tags: ftp, pipe, tcl, stdin, expect

I am uploading a file via ftp using `expect`. The file is piped into my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='example.com'
USER='XXX'
PASSWD='XXX'

expect << EOT
spawn ftp $HOST
expect "Name*:"
send "$USER\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$PASSWD\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "binary\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "prompt\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "put - $1\r"  ####
expect "ftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect eof
EOT
```

On the highlighted line I want ftp to get access to the main script stdin.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key to what you are looking for is Expect's `interact` command. You'd get a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

# Set these in the Tcl way, not the bash way
set HOST "example.com"
set USER "XXX"
set PASSWD "YYY"

# You should recognize this bit...
spawn ftp $HOST
expect "Name*:"
send "$USER\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$PASSWD\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "binary\r"
expect "ftp>"
send "prompt\r"
expect "ftp>"

# New stuff starts here
send "put - [lindex $argv 0]\r"
interact {
    "ftp>" { return }
}
send "bye\r"
wait
exit
```

I've rewritten your script so it doesn't use a here document, because that *would* have interfered with the reading of the content (here-docs are presented as stdin…) and switched it to use a few more idiomatic ways of doing things (idiomatic argument access being the main one).

That said, if I was doing this sort of thing for real, I'd look into using the [`ftp`](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/ftp.html) package from [Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/) as that talks the protocol directly instead of using a possibly-problematic subprocess. (Indeed, if you were going to be doing this on Windows, you'd *have* to do it that way because of quirks of how Expect and FTP.EXE work on that platform).

Comment: I am on Linux platform and something weird is going on:
If I run without pipe, I am able to type something, then ^D and upload works, but interact doesn't return. I have to type bye and so let ftp die.
If I run with pipe, it seems to stuck before sending put 
`ftp> prompt
Interactive mode off.
ftp> ` and I have to `kill -9` but the file gets uploaded (??)